# UnsupportedOperationException on KeyGenerator initialization (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, security, cryptography

With Android 6.0 we have changes, like the BoringSSL library, that replaces OpenSSL.

In my code, I have an initialization for a KeyGenerator:

```
keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm)
keyGenerator.init(256);
```

This works in Android pre 6.0, but in Marshmallow it returns:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot initialize without a android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec parameter
```

How can i init my keygenerator in these devices?

Comment: What's the `algorithm`?

Comment: For me this happens on code `KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "AndroidKeyStore").init(128, new SecureRandom());`

Answer (score 3):

Solved by using SDK 23 and specific code for Android M:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("key1",
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT);
        KeyGenParameterSpec keySpec = builder
                .setKeySize(256)
                .setBlockModes("CBC")
                .setEncryptionPaddings("PKCS7Padding")
                .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(5 * 60)
                .build();
        try {
            this.keyGenerator.init(keySpec);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        // Default KeyGenerator initialization
    }
```